# How to enter values to table string from anther string?

Tags: java, string

I have something here:

```
String b = "Test";  
String a[] = b;
```

How to solve this problem? Why is wrong?
I want to enter values from another string. But how?

Comment: See [Arrays basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: What kind of result are you expecting?

Answer (score 1):

`String a[]` means that `a` is an array of strings. If you want to put `b` in `a` you need to do something like:

```
String a[] = new String[1]; // creates an array of size 1
a[0] = b; // puts b as the first element in a
```

Or equivalently (if you only want a 1-element array),

```
String a[] = {b};
```

Answer (score 1):

`String[] a` is an array.  An array can hold many different values, all of a specific type.

In your example, you don't specify a size for your array, which is necessary.

```
String[] a = new String[1];
a[0] = b;
```

You can also use curly braces to give context to how many elements you wish to enter into the array.  For variables, not literals, the first method works just fine.

```
String[] a = {"Test"};
```